# Add quicklists to gnome items

Tags: gnome, quicklists

Is there a way to add items to the quick-lists in gnome 3.18?
I know it was possible in gnome 3.10 using the '[quicklist'](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/322/quicklists/) extension but that extension is no longer supported in 3.18.
Since gnome 3.18 has native quicklists they should be editable but I can't figure out how.